# Posting content from contentEditible div

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I am trying to make a really simple WYSIWYG text editor. All I am allowing is text and images. These images get appended into the div with jquery using FileReader and appending a img element with the source the base64 of that image.

I am trying to then post this into a database. How should i got about this?

I am using Laravel 4, and the form already posts perfectly fine (using ajax too) but only when using a textarea input. And of course that cannot contain any images so I have since switched the content editible div.

Markup like so:

```
  {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'createpostaction', 'class' => 'newupdateform')) }}
    <div contentEditable="true" id="newupdate-text" class="form-control-addupdate">
      Add text and images...
    </div>
    {{ Form::submit('Post Update', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary submit-newupdate-btn')) }}
  {{ Form::close() }}
```

This was the textarea:

```
  {{ Form::textarea('newupdate-text', Input::old('newupdate-text'), array(
      'class' => 'form-control-addupdate',
      'placeholder' => 'Add update here'
      ))
  }}
```

If I was not using images then I would simply use jQuery to put the text into a textarea, but I want to the posted data to contain the text and the img tag as it is.

I will then process the base64 images etc in PHP.

Any way this is possible or should I be looking at another solution.

Answer (score 0):

An editable div is not a primary form field then will not be present on the array $_POST. Try get the div content using some jQuery like $('#newupdate-text').text();

```
$('.newupdateform').on('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
       url: $(this).attr('action'),
       data: { 
           formContent: $(this).serialize(),
           divContent: $('#newupdate-text').text()
       }   
   })
});
```

Comment: Ill have a play with that and see what I can do. On a side note, didnt think about ever using this.('action') for the url... shall put that to good use in the future.